# AWK multiple patterns

Tags: awk

I have some data like this and I want to extract the Var column for CCC but only for the first three months of 2018 and 2019.

```
ID   Date  Var
--- ------ ---
AAA 201701 110
BBB 201705 211
CCC 201710 312
AAA 201712 413
BBB 201801 514
CCC 201801 615
AAA 201802 716
BBB 201802 817
CCC 201803 918
AAA 201803 119
BBB 201804 220
CCC 201804 321
AAA 201901 222
BBB 201902 312
CCC 201903 111
```

The output should be 615,918,111.

I would like to make a pattern for the dates.

I've tried these so far

```
awk '/CCC/ && /201801/ && /201802/ && /201901/ && /201902/&& /201903/ { print $3 } ' file.txt

awk ' $1 ~ /CCC/ || /201801/ && /201802/ && /201901/ && /201902/&& /201903/ { print $3 } ' file.txt
```

Comment: But 918 and 111 are from 3rd month.

Comment: Sorry I meant first three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$1 == "CCC" && $2 ~ /201[89]0[123]/{print $3}' filename
```

output

```
615
918
111
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
u=re.compile(r'201[89]0[123]')
k=open('filename','r')
k.read
for i in k:
    j=i.split(' ')
    if j[0] == "CCC":
        if re.search ( u,j[1]):
            print j[2].strip()
```

output

```
615
918
111
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following `awk`

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /CCC/ && $2 ~ /201(8|9)0(1|2|3)/ {print $3}' file.txt
615
918
111
```

**UPDATE**

For average:

```
awk '$1 ~ /CCC/ && $2 ~ /201(8|9)0(1|2|3)/ {print $3; sum+=$3; n+=1} END { print "Average: " sum/n }' file.txt
615
918
111
Average: 548
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: How could I get the average

Comment: @entropee I updated the answer.

Comment: Can you explain the n+=1

Comment: @entropee  every time it matches the specified conditions, the value at Var column will be added to `sum` and `n` will be incremented by 1. we do this because finally we need the number of items for calculating average.

Comment: @entropee Please always accept an answer to the question you have asked, 
without adding new questions that require modifications on the existing answers.
[Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) should be avoided. You can ask a new question if you don't have the answer on a following task you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you only have one pattern in `$0` and could save a few characters of typing by

```
awk '/CCC 201[89]0[1-3]/{print $3; s+=$3; n++}END{print s/n}' file
615
918
111
548
```